# How to add interval time in angulajs.?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, momentjs

I'm implementing analog and digital clock, but problem is, time is not showing live time, how to set time interval for this to refresh time every second?

```
$scope.TimeZ = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
function TimeZoneDetails(time, date, content, name) {
    this.Time = time;
    this.Date = date;
    this.Content = content;
    this.Name = name;
}
$scope.LstTimeZoneDetails = [];

$($scope.TimeZone.split(", ")).each(function (key, value) {
    var objTimeZoneDetails = new TimeZoneDetails(moment.tz(value).format('LT'),
        moment.tz(value).format('LL'),
        moment.tz.zone(value).abbr(moment.utc().valueOf()),
        moment.tz.zone(value).name);
    //push values to array
    $scope.LstTimeZoneDetails.push(objTimeZoneDetails);
    timedUpdate();
})
```

[image]

Comment: You need to change time to particular timezone ?

Comment: You can use momentjs library for timezone.
https://momentjs.com/

Comment: yes im using that moment.js although time is not updating

Answer (score 2):

Angular itself has no interval, you can use.

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 1 * 1000);

function myCallback() {
  console.log('Time');
}
```

Replace "**1**" with your desire time.
For now interval is set for **1 second**

To destory or stop the interval use.

```
clearInterval(intervalID);
```

Comment: thanks but but i need to set interval for above script how? i tried your code its working int normal scenario but for above script its not showing

Answer (score 1):

As of AngularJS [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

what u need is: `$timeout([fn], [delay], [invokeApply], [Pass]);`

In your case:

```
// Set the delay in milliseconds: 1000ms = 1s
var delayInterval = 1000;

// A function to update the time
function updateTime() {
    // Some code to update time...
}

// Pass the updateTime function as first parameter and the deplayInterval as the second parameter to the AngularJS $timeout function.
$timeout(updateTime, delayInterval);
```

In the `updateTime()` function you can put code (whatever you need) that you want to be executed in intervals, then your `updateTime()` function will be called each `delayInterval` milliseconds.